# To whom the kill will be assigned in Fortnite Duo, Trio team member?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Please, does anyone know how the kill assignment is computed in Fortnite in Duo/Trio? For example, if three members from the same team shoot an enemy at the same time who will get the kill?  The last one or the one how did the most damage?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The kill credit is always assigned to the person who does the final blow, blows done after the enemy is downed to not count towards this. It is also practically impossible for two(or more) players to hit another player at the ***exact*** same time, so that situation will never happen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it is not based on the most impact (damage),  it's assigned to the person who does the final blow!